# Master/Slave - streaming replication restrict function to master

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, pgpool

How can I run a `function a` on master only?

I don't want to connect directly to my master server, because the master server might change.

Or can I change my function to work on this setup? Because at the moment using the below function, will say that the server is read-only?

```
ERROR:  cannot execute SELECT in a read-only transaction

CREATE FUNCTION.....
 WITH sel AS (
   SELECT id
   FROM   univ.domains
   WHERE  name = domain_name
  )
, ins AS (
  INSERT INTO univ.domains (name)
  SELECT domain_name
  WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sel)
  RETURNING id
  )
SELECT id
FROM   sel NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN ins 
INTO   domain_id;
 ...
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Also tried adding `SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE;` after `begin` and got:

```
cannot set transaction read-write mode inside a read-only transaction
```

Comment: So, I don't know where your original question is, but: you can write only on a master.  There is no other way.  However, there is a way to decouple the application from the (possibly changing) cluster role (I mean master/slave).  We use an additional, separate IP address for both the master and slave (dubbed a service IP).  When failing over, we move over the IP, too - which, in turn, has a host name defined in DNS.  This was, for example, `order.internal.domain` always points to the master, while `order-slave.internal.domain` always points to the slave.